# Complex number and orthogonal axis

Tags: complex-numbers, orthogonality

What are the properties of complex numbers which allow us to plot the real and complex part on orthogonal axis?
One thing I understand is that complex portion cannot be represented as scalar multiple of real part (treating real as scalars) so they are independent (i.e., $c_1R+c_2i=0$ only if $c_1=c_2=0$).

Further, the definition of modulus of a complex number is same as $L_2-norm$.

Are these reasons sufficient for this representation or is there more to it?

Comment: I don't think there's a unique answer to this, but as you suggest, the fact that they are independent is one way of looking at it. More to the point, $\mathbb C$ is a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$, so for the purposes of 'drawing a grid' on the complex numbers, you can do it with nice consistent orthogonal coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orthogonality comes from the definition of $i$:  $i \times i + 1 \times 1 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have answered your question yourself.
They are independent, therefore, orthogonal.
Like x and y in regular Cartesian space, they are by definition, orthogonal.

There is NO need for notion such as xx + yy = 0, as the other answer suggests, where x and y are the unit vectors of the 2 components of the Cartesian place.
It might have confused with the calculation of vector's angle using dot product, i.e. 0 dot product means they are orthogonal. But what's wrong is that dot product is using the coefficients which are real numbers, not unit vectors themselves.

Comment: "They are independent, *therefore* orthogonal" sounds like a next level of wrong. Orthogonality depends on the scalar/hermitian form. Independence is a weaker condition (in the positive-definite case).

Comment: Please provide an answer yourself to this question, at high school math level. Thanks.